# Submit form without refreshing page using gwt and gwtbootstrap3

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I am using gwt and gwtbootstrap3 for my gwt project. My code looks like

```
  <b:NavbarForm pull="LEFT">
      <b:TextBox placeholder="Search" addStyleNames="col-lg-8"/>
    </b:NavbarForm>
```

Now if I type anything in the textbox and hit enter, gwt is reloading whole page, which I do not wants, All I wants is to get the value from the text box and call a method. Is there any way I can achieve that.

FYI, I can fetch the value if I do not use NavbarForm but then I can not make search box inline.

http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#navbar

FYI, just an update if I wrap the text box in some other container like NavbarText or NavbarNav the UI got corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bug in gwtbootstrap3 - they did an overhaul of the Form widget recently.

But for now, you can add a `SubmitHandler` to your `NavbarForm` and cancel the `SubmitEvent` to prevent it from reloading the page:

```java
navbarForm.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        event.cancel();
    }
});
```

When using UiBinder:

```java
@UiHandler("navbarForm")
void onNavbarSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
    event.cancel();
}
```

Note that in this case `SubmitEvent` is of type `org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.base.form.AbstractForm.SubmitEvent`, **not** `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel.SubmitEvent`.

Comment: I am using UiBinder and when I tried to add @UiHandler("navbarForm") it gave me error `[ERROR] Field 'navbarForm' does not have an 'addFormPanel.SubmitHandler' method associated`.

Comment: Thank for your response but I could not find `org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.base.form.AbstractForm.SubmitEvent` class and I have gwtbootstrap3-0.8.1.jar` in my classpath

Comment: It's in 0.9 version, it's recently been released. It should be available on Maven Central: https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/issues/247